# How to show a base64 as downloadable link in the HTML?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this list of base64 returning from sprinboot service as this object inside object "Ticket":

```
ticketFiles: Array(1)
0: {id: 475, ticketFile: "data:text/plain;base64,Wz8xMy8/MDEvPzIwMjAgMTE6MDZ…rZXIgZGEgU2lsdmE6ICANCkRlcG9pcyBwb2RlIHNpbQ0KIA0K"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I am now creating the view in angular and I need to show this as a link downloadable:

```
<div class="col s12">
    <h4>Ticket Files</h4>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let ticketFile of ticket.ticketFiles">
                <td>{{ticketFile.ticketFile}}</td>
</tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

But this way it's only showing the base64 as a plain text.
So, how can I create a link with the name of the file "e.g: "ferias.txt" and this link downloads the file?

Answer (score 0):

Download resources using the `a` tag

```js
let dl = document.createElement("a");

dl.href = baseData; // "data:text/plain;base64,Wz8xMy8/MDEvPzIwMjAgMTE6MDZ…rZXIgZGEgU2lsdmE6ICANCkRlcG9pcyBwb2RlIHNpbQ0KIA0K"

dl.download = "filename.txt";

dl.click();
```

or use template rendering

```html
<tr *ngFor="let ticketFile of ticket.ticketFiles">
  <td>
   <a download="{{ticketFile.id}}.txt" [href]="ticketFile.ticketFile"> 
      {{ticketFile.id}}.txt
   </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Where should I put the first piece?
let dl = document.createElement("a");

dl.href = baseData; // "data:text/plain;base64,Wz8xMy8/MDEvPzIwMjAgMTE6MDZ…rZXIgZGEgU2lsdmE6ICANCkRlcG9pcyBwb2RlIHNpbQ0KIA0K"

dl.download = "filename.txt";

dl.click();

Comment: The link is starting with "unsafe" tag like this "unsafe:data:text/plain;base64,Wz8xMy8/MDEvPzIwMjA" ... and it doess not let me to download.

Comment: You can use the first method to download in the event of click download

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this fully in js

```
ticketFile = data // link the data to this variable 
 const file = window.btoa(binary);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
          a.href = file;
          a.download = fileName.txt;

<div class="col s12">
    <h4>Ticket Files</h4>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let ticketFile of ticket.ticketFiles">
                <td><a [href]="ticketFile.ticketFile">{{ticketFile.ticketFile}}</a></td>
</tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```